# Can I use the wildcard for table name while selecting from multiple table?

Tags: sql, sybase

My problem is there are multiple tables like `table_1, table_2,...,table_100`

Now I want to query from all tables at once, is that possible?

Right now I am using SQL like this

```
select * from table_1
union
select * from table_2
union
.
.
```

Comment: No, you can't.  Having multiple tables with the same columns is usually a sign of a poor database design.  You should have a single table with an additional column.

Comment: If you are applying `union` with `select *`, all those tables must contain same column types. And if all tables are similar, why did you create 100 tables? Why don't you create a single table with an extra column?

Comment: This would generally suggest that the data model is broken. If all of these tables contain the same "type" of data, such that it makes sense to perform this union, why isn't all of this data in *one* table (with additional column(s) to specify the *data* that's probably currently embedded in the table *names*)

Comment: the thing is I have not accutally designed the database and each table consist of large number of datas and it is created daywise